# Regex for Han char and English with Boundary

Tags: java, regex, unicode

> [Resolved!! Change font type to accommodate spacing.]

I want a boundary of 6 characters that consists of english and chinese characters. This is to achieve the result below :

```
Name     Status
---------------
name     R
name名字 R
名字
nameb名  R
字名字
```

> However, the results seems to be appearing like this instead

```
Name     Status
---------------
name     R
name名字   R
名字
nameb名   R
字名字
```

To be able to align them closely is good enough. But from what I am observing, it seems like its reading the chinese characters first, then printing the number of spaces to fill in the remaining space.

```
List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
String msg = "name名字名字";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b.{1,5}\\b\\W?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(msg);

while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Debugging : " + m.group().trim());   // Debug
        res.add(m.group());
}

for (int i=0; i<res.size(); i++)
{
    String temp = "R";
    s.append(String.format("%-6s  %-6s",res.get(i), temp));
    temp = "";
}
```

Is it my regex or my String.format issue?

Comment: Either it's simply a font issue, or `String.format` evaluates the *East Asian Width* property and treats *Fullwidth* characters as taking up two spaces.

Comment: is there any reference i can refer to in regards to the _East Asian Width_ and _Fullwidth_?

Comment: First, you should rule out that it's a font issue. Do Han characters take up two spaces on your screen? Then you should try a different font. If Han characters take up a single space, then you can simply pad the string manually: `while (name.codePointCount(0, name.length()) < 6) { name = name + " "; }`

Comment: Thanks! I changed my font type and it works. I worked with Han characters taking 2 spacing so it would ease my calculation.